# Do we really need the eigenvectors of $A$ to find $e^{tA}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, cayley-hamilton

For an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we can express

$$e^{tA} = \alpha_1(t)I + \alpha_2(t)A + \cdots + \alpha_n(t)A^{n-1}$$

where the coefficients $\alpha_i$ could easily be found by replacing the matrix by eigenvalues in the above expression or its derivatives in case of repeated eigenvalues.

Why do we need to find eigenvectors at all to calculate the matrix exponential, or even to find solutions to the systems of linear differential equations, when we can find solutions without eigenvectors?

Comment: No, the eigenvalues are enough: you can compute the exponential using the generalized interpolation polynomial of the exponential function on the eigenvalues, then applying this polynomial to the matrix $tA$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula#Generalization).

Comment: I guess that diagonalisation is the easiest way to evaluate the exponential of a matrix, as well as the $n$-th power of a generic matrix.

Comment: @the_candyman No, it isn't. It is the laziest way for instructors to explain.

Comment: @the_candyman Depends. Numerically, there are [many methods](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf). Using the Taylor series on the matrix scaled be $2^{-k}$ then squaring is fairly simple, for instance.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Right. I change my statement. It is the easiest way if you want a precise computation in a symbolic context. At least, it is the easiest that I know!

Comment: In fact, a very fast method for computing matrix exponentials is by solving a system of ODEs: http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/linear-algebra/matrix-exponential/matrix-exponential.html

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for your comment, I fixed my error.

Comment: I got the system $\dot \alpha =  C \alpha$, where $C$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: A good question. I suppose (restricting to the simple case of distinct eigenvalues) a way here would be to write $A^n$ as a solution of the recurrence relation coming from Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Hmm. I'm no longer sure what I had in mind is feasible :-(